# how to reset value when page is reload in session bean?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my page(search page), there are one search text box and primefaces treetable. when page is reload this two fields cannot reset and still have data that are previous search.
I have also other pages, but no need to do reset value when page is reload and can reset data automatically. what is problem of that page(search page).
Can someone answer my problem? Thanks :)

Comment: Just put the data in a bean in the desired scope.

Comment: You may have a look at `<f:viewAction action="#{myBean.myInit()}"`. It will be called on a GET request, but not on a POST request.

Comment: Ok, i'll try first. :)